# Bypass Native Dialer App And Place a Call

Tags: react-native, phone-call, android-dialer

Good Day Everyone, I have an app idea I'll soon be implementing with react native, it's kinda a calling app but i want to know if it's possible to place a call directly from my app without launching the native **phone/dialer** app...I want to know if it's possible with any programming language, framework, or library, Even tho it's react I'll be using. Thanks..

Comment: Did you explore .   https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-call

Comment: Thanks alot... really looks like i found an answer

Comment: Hi @Stanley can I please know the library or the answer you used? I have a similar problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library for the purpose to bypass native dialer app 
[react-native-phone-call](http://%20npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-call)